# Ubuntu 16.04 on Acer Aspire 5338 has issues

Tags: acer, aspire

On Sunday I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Acer Aspire 5338 laptop. Since then, I've had nothing but problems. The screen freezes constantly, it regularly boots up to a blank black screen, it's really slow and the Image Viewer and Archive Manager won't work after first use. It's crashed twice and I get System Program has a problem pop-ups even after I've already clicked the 'report problem' option.

How do I solve these issues.?

Comment: Acer Aspire 5338 has a not-so-good Intel GMA4500 integrated graphics and a 2009 entry level Celeron. Do not expect miracles with that hardware. Also the HDD, if original, is about to fail if it haven't yet (t may even be part of the problem). That said, a question: Have you used a recently downloaded Ubuntu ISO file (should be 16.04.1) or older?

Comment: Why is the HDD about to fail.? And yes, I did use a recently downloaded ISO file, 16.04.01 LTS

Comment: Because it's a 7-8 years old HDD working in a consumer grade ACER notebook, the ones not know for not over-heating at times? The point being you notebook is quite "old" so everything you described can be hardware related. Have you tested it with the original Windows Vista?

Comment: I had no problems at all with the original Vista, the only reason I changed to Ubuntu was because support for Vista is rapidly running out. The laptop itself works fine. It's never over-heated, never crashed with Vista, is still in very good condition.

Comment: Good. Knowing that, I would reinstall Ubuntu 16.04.1 and run all the updates. I've noticed some of your other questions and understand you had some difficulties before so I suggest you use the default option of "erase disk and install..."

Comment: You might have much better luck with ubuntu 14.04.1 since 16.04 has no data on it yet. You can dual boot with Vista until that breaks some day.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general how to troubleshoot computers type of question than a specific Ubuntu or Acer laptop question.

Since you're having intermittent boot issues, I would recommend scanning the hard drive for errors as a first step, before anything else. It's easy enough to [check the SMART status](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) and see if anything is starting to go bad. I wouldn't say your drive IS about to fail, it may be perfectly fine depending on power on hours and other variables. If the drive is good, then there's no reason that would be causing the problems you're experiencing, so move on to the next step.

My next step would be in Ubuntu to upgrade the video driver. [Intel provides a tool for this which is supported in Ubuntu 16.04](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2)

Another thing to keep in mind is that newer distros may not necessarily be better than older ones considering the aging hardware. Take a look at [Lubuntu 12.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.04/release/) or maybe [14.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/14.04/release/).

Aside of all that, random crashes can be hardware or software. Capacitors can leak, making chipsets and the CPU unstable, leading to unexpected hangs or shutdowns. It's difficult to diagnose these kinds of problems without looking at the physical state of the computer or at least testing software that you know should work fine (reinstall Windows for a few days as a test).

Good luck!